# How to upgrade 14.04 to 16 without internet and access to bios?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I'd like to upgrade 14.04 to 16 on a notebook which has neither the internet access, no access to bios or change boot sequence option. No CD drive either. I only have a working usb. Can I do that?

Comment: Can you add iso files to your ubuntu sources and update that way? I've never done it, but have seen cd roms specified as sources for packages so figured this could be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Source: [debian administration site](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)

Main requirements include:

- usb
- another pc with connection to internet

So eventually an internet connection is needed but since you're just using the *usb* on it it gives you less hassles as you can use another pc with better internet connection than yours.

I haven't done this before but you may try this and see if it goes well, read the information the link given above before moving forward.

First off you need to install **opt-offline** as its needed to do an offline upgrade.

`sudo apt-get install apt-offline`

Steps:

1. generate the apt signature file used for searching for needed packages from source:

   - `sudo apt-offline set ~/apt.sig`
   - incase you need any extra packages then do:

     - `sudo apt-offline --update --upgrade --install-package package_to_install -- ~/apt.sig`
2. Copy the *apt.sig* file generated and put that on a **USB** and take that to where you can get internet access.
3. On new pc (with internet) run this command from the terminal after inserting the usb:

   - `apt-offline get -d /path/to/download/directory /path/to/apt.sig`
   - for windows: `apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --threads 5`

     - Note: the `--thread` creates 5 download threads to speed up the download
4. Or use the `--bundle` option and run same as **step 3**

   - `apt-offline get --bundle /download/path/aptbundle.zip /path/to/apt.sig`
5. Take the USB back to your Ubuntu and plug USb and run command:

   - `sudo apt-offline install /path/to/aptbundle.zip`
6. Now upgrade your Ubuntu.

Comment: Another pc available for me has Windows on it. What should I do on step 3 above in my case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have updated the answer and please have a look [here](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)

Comment: On step 5 I get the message (in red)ERROR: I couldn't understand file type 'extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release.gpg Then there are several screens of messages ending with the word synced. After reboot it is still 14.04

Comment: did you add extra packages with step 1 ? Please posts the errors.

Comment: Sorry left out `apt-get upgrade` . did you run that ?

Comment: I correct myself - there have been error messages on step 4. It said that it failed to download several files. All of them are translations, but three http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease.lzma http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease.lzma http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease.lzma

Comment: you used step 4 rather than step 3 ?

Comment: Yes, I fould a pc with ubuntu and working internet connection and used step 4 rather than 3.